# Usage of simple past and past continuous tenses in this example

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

Are both sentences grammatically accurate, and how does the meaning differ if at all?

Grandma May knitted a sweater while she was listening to music.

Grandma May was knitting a sweater while she listened to music.

Comment: *Accurate* isn't really the right word here.  *Correct* would be a better word to use.  *Accurate* means something more like "reporting something correctly".

Comment: Both versions are syntactically fine. So are the other two permutations: *Grandma May knitted a sweater while she listened to music* (both Simple Past) and *Grandma May was knitting a sweater while she was listening to music* (both Past Continuous). Which version should be "preferred" depends on the *exact* context (and/or the exact nuance of meaning you want to convey).

Comment: Note that idiomatically, we often don't bother with unnecessary pronouns and/or auxiliary verbs, so *Grandma May knitted a sweater **while listening** to music* is far more likely than your first version, *whatever* the exact context and intended nuance.